# Automatic NuGet symbols package generation on VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget-package

On VisualStudio 2017 there is a checkbox to automate the NuGet package generation on build when compiling .net core libraries.

But I have to generate the symbols package manually. Is there a way to automate it?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can create a batch file and execute it post build (ie. post build script).

Comment: I am searching for that too. I think we have to do it with post build commands